# Determine the number of different variable names

Tags: combinatorics

Let name of a variable be a string of between 1 and 65535, inclusive, where each character can be an uppercase or a lowercase letter , a dollar sign, an underscore or a digit, except that the first character must not be a digit. What is the number of different variable names possible ?
Solution

1. Given that the first char must not be a digit, this first character can be chosen in 26(lowercase) + 26(uppercase) + 1(dollar sign) + 1(underscore) = 54 ways.
2. All subsequent chars can be chosen in $64^{65534}$ ways. As each subsequent digit cab be chosen in (26(uppercase) + 26(lowercase) + 1(dollar sign) + 1(underscore) + 10(digits)) = 64. As there are 65534 digits left, to get the number of possible combination 64 is multiplied 65534 times = $64^{65534}$.
3. Hence total number of possible names is: 
   $$
   54 * 64^{65534}
   $$
   Can this be the correct answer or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Could you explain, how you did get $64^{65536}-1$ ?

Comment: that is a mistake. corrected it to $64^{65535}$....

Comment: What happened to the $54$?  How can the possibly not be relevant to your final answer?  And why do you say there are $65535$ digits left?  The string is anywhere from $1$ to $65535$ characters long, it certainly isn't $65536$.  You are definitely missing something.

Comment: This is wrong; see the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). A variable name is an identifier. The characters in an identifier are not limited to the ones you list; the specification states only that these are *included*, immediately going on to say that others are included, too. Also, according to the specification, there is no length limit; if you encountered a length limit, it may have been imposed by a non-compliant implementation.

Comment: It is not about JAVA (corrected that). Main goal - is to find number of possible combinations given the conditions.

Comment: @ortymd Now it looks right.

Comment: great! Thanks for checking =)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

$$54(65^0)+54(64^1)+54(64^2)+...+54(64^{65534})$$

Apply the formula of sum of geometry series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n ar^i = \frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}, if r \neq 1$$

The nicer answer is:

$$\frac{54(64^{65535} - 1)}{63}$$

You have to take variable length into account. Your solution is only for variables of max length.